# Find the index of an array element

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently practicing arrays using an [exercise](https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/array/index.php).

I had a look in the solution of the given exercise and I don't quite understand what is happening there.

Can someone please explain this step by step to me?

```
public class GettingIndexOfAnArray {

    public static int findIndex(int[] my_array, int t) {
        if (my_array == null) return -1;
        int len = my_array.length;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < len) {
            if (my_array[i] == t) return i;
            else i = i + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] my_array = {25, 14, 56, 15, 36, 56, 77, 18, 29, 49};
        System.out.println("Index position of 25 is: " + 
        findIndex(my_array, 25));
        System.out.println("Index position of 77 is: " + 
        findIndex(my_array, 77));
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty straightforward: Runs over the array until it finds the element `t` then returns the index `i` where it was found (or -1 if it was not found).

Comment: The `findIndex` method is simply scanning the array looking for a value.  If you don't understand this, then you might want to hit a Java tutorial.

Comment: What don't you understand here ? what part causes you some trouble ? What do you expect it to do ?

Comment: Searching/finding in arrays is sub-optiomal. The structure was not made for this. The only way is to iterate from start to end until found. Use different structures like hashed once if you need fast `contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

The method searches the array from its start to the end until it found the element.

Let's take a closer look at the method:

```
public static int findIndex(int[] my_array, int t) {
    if (my_array == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    int len = my_array.length;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        if (my_array[i] == t) {
            return i;
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The method accepts two parameters, the array `my_array` and the element to search for `t`.

The method directly aborts if the passed array is `null`:

```
if (my_array == null) {
    return -1;
}
```

Returning `-1` means "*element was not found*".

Next the method setups a loop that is supposed to iterate from start to end:

```
int len = my_array.length;
int i = 0;
while (i < len) {
    ...
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Inside the loop the method checks the value of the array at the current index against the given value:

```
if (my_array[i] == t) {
    return i;
}
```

If the values match, the element was found and the current index `i` is returned.

If not, the loop continues the iteration. If the loop ends, the value could not be found since all elements were checked. Thus, the method returns `-1` in the end.

---

### Notes

In Java variable names should use *camelCase* and no underscores, so `myArray` would be a better name. The name itself could be improved too, how about `values`.

The method itself can be made easier to read:

```
public static int findIndex(int[] values, int valueToSearch) {
    // No values to search through
    if (values == null || values.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Iterate all values
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] == valueToSearch) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    // All values were iterated, value was not found
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass in an `array` and a value to find (`t`) into `findIndex()`

First it checks for `null`, and returns -1 (i.e. not found) if `null`

Then it sets `len` to the length of the `array`

Then it loops from position 0 of the `array`

On each iteration, it checks if the position of `t` (`t` being the value you're looking for) matches the position in the `array` (first iteration is 0, the first element of the `array`)

If they match, it returns the position in the `array`

It keeps iterating until it matches, or if it doesn't, it returns -1 (again, -1 being not found).